# using struct elements in function that is in another source file

Tags: c

New to learning c and I am having difficulties with writing a function in another source file that uses struct variables from the first source file.

basically I need to create a bubblesort function in another file to be used in my driver

this is what i am trying to do

**driver.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sort.c>
typedef struct iorb {
        int base_pri;
        struct iorb *link;
        char filler[100];
} IORB;

int main(){
sort();
}
```

**sort.h**

```
void sortList(IORB * head, int(*prio)(int));
```

**sort.c**

```
void sortList(IORB * head, int(*prio)(int)){
// do stuff
}
```

but i get this error:
unknown type IORB in the sort function.

how can pass the IORB to the function ?

Updated code after trying the answer:
**driver.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "sort.h"
#include "iorb.h"
  //removed the typedef in the driver
```

**iorb.h**

```
#ifndef IORB_H
#define IORB_H

typedef struct iorb {
        int base_pri;
        struct iorb *link;
        char filler[100];
} IORB;

#endif
```

**sort.h**

```
#ifndef SORT_H_
#define SORT_H_


void sortList(IORB * head, int(*prio)(int));

#endif
```

**sort.c**

```
#include "sort.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "iorb.h"


void sortList(IORB * head, int(*prio)(int)){
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: Put the `typedef` into a header file and include that header into both C files.

Comment: You shouldn't use `#include` to include `.c` files.

Comment: To @marco-a point, you normally build *.o files for each .c file, then link them to together in the final binary.  You can also do it in one step, for example `gcc sort.c main.c -o sort` (just be careful sort is a standard unix utility so call it with ./sort)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to put your type declaration / typedef in a header file:

```
#ifndef IORB_H
#define IORB_H

typedef struct iorb {
        int base_pri;
        struct iorb *link;
        char filler[100];
} IORB;

#endif
```

Then include that header file in `sort.h`:

```
#include "iorb.h"
```

and you want to include the `sort.h` in your `sort.c`:

```
#include "sort.h"
```

Comment: Yeah, I erased it from existence.

Comment: this still gives me unknown type name IORB

Comment: It's the correct solution.  Can you update your question with the code you have now?

Comment: You need `#include "iorb.h"` in sort.h.